# Greek language in section titles

Tags: greek

I want to write some greek text in a section title, but not entirely. I use

```
\subsection[Sud. s.v.]{\selectlanguage{italian} Sud. s.v.\foreignlanguage{greek}{Ἰσαῖος}}
```

and it works. The problem is, in my table of contents the greek word does not appear.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When you specify an optional argument to `\subsection`, that text will be used for the table of contents. A `\selectlanguage` command should never go in a title anyway. Can you make a small compilable example?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, as the problem is not about the language switch or the peculiarities of Greek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
\subsection[short text]{long text}
```

the table of contents will contain “short text”, so the behavior you report is expected.

Here is an example. Note that `\selectlanguage` should never be used in a section title (and is very rarely needed anyway, for that matter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Prova}
\author{MM}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Titolo}

\subsection{Sud. s.v. \foreignlanguage{greek}{Ἰσαῖος}}

\end{document}
```

[image]